# How to do some infinite task with Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I need to "enable and disable the firewall" continuously using robot framework.

I have written following robot testcase for this purpose:

```
testcase1
    Open Connection                         1.1.1.1
    Login                                   test    test
    Write                                   firewall enable
    Write                                   commit
    Write                                   firewall disable
    Write                                   commit
```

The above testcase doing the task as expected but only one time. But I want to do this continuously (infinite).

Any clue please? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put it inside a for loop. It is not infinite but if you put large enough value it is close enough for practical purposes. This will create a huge log file.

```
testcase1
    :FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    999999
    \    Open Connection    ${TEST}
    \    Rest of code
```

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops

Answer (score 2):

To run truly infinite loop you can do something like this:
Create python file lib.py:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def call_keyword(keyword):
    return BuiltIn().run_keyword(keyword)
    
def run_endless_loop(f):
    while True:
        call_keyword(f)
```

then in your robot file you can do something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  lib.py

*** Keywords ***
My keyword
    Log To Console  Hello World

*** Test Cases ***
Run endless loop
    Run Endless Loop  My keyword
```

This will run endless loop. The only problem left is to how to break the loop, if needed.To break the loop by the condition from robot file you can implement somethin like:

```
def run_endless_loop(f):
    while True:
        i = call_keyword(f)
        if i == 100:
            break
```

could be a counter, or some string condition, or something else.