# Running couple of tests in robot framework infinitely

Tags: robotframework

How can I run a couple of tests in robot framework infinitely or atleast a large number of times finitely.

Eg:

Test case 1
.
.
.

Test case 2
.
.
.
Test case 3
.
.
.
I want Tests to run in the order 1,2,3,1,2,3... finitely (for a large number) or infinitely.

I know how to do it for a single test. But I want it to come back and do test 1 after test 3. And i want this batch to run in a loop.

Comment: Hmm yes, very usefull for us to work with. Great job!

Comment: You could create a batch file which calls your .robot file. This batch file would have a infinite loop (while true loop).. That should do the trick..?

Comment: @Goralight - That is a good idea. Only thing is that it will end up generating new report.html/log.html each time. It will be useful if I can have the result in a single report.html

Comment: Add a `rebot` command to the end of the batch file after the "kill key" has been entered? You still get single reports, but least it bundles them together once the infinite loop has been killed. Other than that, I dont know of a way to do what youre asking within RF

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30288294/4278756 is as close as your are going to get to a infinite loop. I recommend doing a Batch file as least then you have every report created - I dont know how the linked answer would cope if RF suddenly died, if you would get any reports at all. Rather have too many than 0, IMO.

Comment: thanks @Goralight It is true and useful if RF suddenly dies and I am left with no reports. Happened many times :-(

Comment: alternative to @Goralight, you may use Robot listener which will provide realtime execution status: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface

Comment: @jozefow - That's great. Thanks for introducing to listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create a infinite loop within RF which will run the current file over and over again indefinitely. Instead, you could create a script which points to the RF file, handles the infinity(ness) for you, and then when needed to, kill the process and join all the `output.xml`'s together, creating the mother of all mothers RF reports. Here is a quick example within Python:

```
import subprocess
import os
import glob

try:
    while True:
        subprocess.call("robot EnterFileNameHere.robot")  # Add any robot options you may want
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    total = []
    os.chdir("/DirectoryWhich/HasAll/TheXML/Files")
    for GrabbedFiles in glob.glob("*.xml"):
        total += GrabbedFiles
    Converted = " ".join(str(x) for x in total)
    subprocess.call("rebot {0}".format(Converted))  # Add any rebot options you may want
```

Change the directories to match where your files are, and this should infinitely fire off your robot file of choice, constantly creating report files / output files. Once you kill it (with CTRL+C) it will accept that as a `KeyboardInterrupt` which will then, merge all of the output files for you, and then close the terminal.

The only other way to do this within RF itself is by this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30288294/4278756) but this would only generate a report for you once the loop is completed. I do not know how it would handle report generation if you suddenly killed RF. I presume it wouldn't create any reports at all. So personally, I think this is your best bet.

Any questions let me know.